# What is the difference between pumping Lemma for regualar languages and pumping lemma for context free languages?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

Is there a difference between the pumping lemma for regular languages and the context-free languages?
I know that pumping lemma for context-free languages is a generalization of pumping lemma for regular languages. However, there are some languages that are not regular but context-free languages. for example the language ww^-1 is context-free but not regular.
So, what is the difference between the two demonstrations?

Comment: If you read the descriptions of the pumping lemma for both, you'll see that any regular language pump is also a context-free pump, but not vice-versa.

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307465/pumping-lemma-for-cfl-vs-pumping-lemma-for-regular-languages?rq=1)